# Does Lightning to 3.5 mm support High-Res headphones?

Tags: ios, audio, headphones, lightning

Since iPhone 7, Apple has switched to Lightning port and provides a dongle for 3.5 mm jack. Does this dongle support High-Res (16/24 bit) headphones/earphones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High resolution headphones work with the same analog signal as ordinary head phones. High resolution headphones “just” have to be compliant with some quality requirements for the head phones themselves. There’s no guarantee that a pair of high resolution headphones are better than a given pair of non-high resolution headphones.

Therefore yes, you can use them with the Apple Lighting dongle.